# How do I set properties on parent object if any children (recursive) match a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```js
let testData = [
  {
    name: "fruit",
    checked: false,
    isOpen: false,
    childrens: [
      {
        name: "apple",
        checked: false,
        isOpen: false,
        childrens: [
          {
            name: "one",
            checked: false
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "animal",
    checked: false,
    isOpen: false,
    childrens: [
      {
        name: "people",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: "123",
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to select one that includes its superiors.

I try to use the code myself:

```js
function recursive(name, arr) {
  arr.forEach((item) = > {
    test(name, item)
  });
  arrData = arr
}

function test(name, item) {
  if (item.childrens && item.childrens.length > 0) {
    item.childrens.forEach(sub = > {
      test(name, sub)
    })
  }
  if (name == item.name) {
    item.isOpen = !item.isOpen
    item.checked = !item.checked
  }
  return item
}
var arrData = []
let name = "one"
recursive(name, testData)
```

But I chose `one`, I didn't select `fiuit` `apple`

The result I want is this:

```js
let result = [
  {
    name: "fruit",
    checked: true,
    isOpen: true,
    childrens: [
      {
        name: "apple",
        checked: true,
        isOpen: true,
        childrens: [
          {
            name: "one",
            checked: true
          }
        ]
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    name: "animal",
    checked: false,
    isOpen: false,
    childrens: [
      {
        name: "people",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: "123",
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Could you help me? thank you

Comment: Your desired result seems to be the same as your input?

Comment: @Nick No, `isOpen`、`hecked`  becomes `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your `recursive` and `test` functions into one function; checking whether the current object or any of its children matches the name, toggling the `checked` and `isOpen` flags and returning `true` if so:

```
function test(name, arr) {
  found = false;
  arr.forEach(o => {
    if (o.name == name || o.childrens && test(name, o.childrens)) {
      o.checked = !o.checked;
      o.isOpen = !o.isOpen;
      found = true;
    }
  });
  return found;
}
```

```js
let testData = [{
    name: "fruit",
    checked: false,
    isOpen: false,
    childrens: [{
      name: "apple",
      checked: false,
      isOpen: false,
      childrens: [{
        name: "one",
        checked: false
      }]
    }, ]
  },
  {
    name: "animal",
    checked: false,
    isOpen: false,
    childrens: [{
        name: "people",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: "123",
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  }
]

function test(name, arr) {
  found = false;
  arr.forEach(o => {
    if (o.name == name || o.childrens && test(name, o.childrens)) {
      o.checked = !o.checked;
      o.isOpen = !o.isOpen;
      found = true;
    }
  });
  return found;
}

test('one', testData);
console.log(testData);
test('one', testData);
console.log(testData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it. Though you ran the function on each child, you didn't check what the result of that was.

In the code below I reordered the `test` function slightly and have added comments to help.

I noticed that you currently don't handle what happens if the parent was to get unchecked - would it then uncheck all children recursively?

```js
function test(name, item) {
    let closeChildren   = false,
        uncheckChildren = false;
    // do this first so we don't modify after checking children
    if(item.name === name){
        if(item.isOpen){
            // close item
            item.isOpen = false;

            // flag children to be closed
            closeChildren = true;
        }else{
            item.isOpen = true;
        }

        if(item.checked){
            // uncheck item
            item.checked = false;

            // flag children to be unchecked
            uncheckChildren = true;

        }else{
            item.checked = true;
        }
    }

    // make sure the current item has `childrens` property
    if(item.childrens !== undefined){
        for(let i = 0, l = item.childrens.length;i < l;i++){
            // check what the result was of running `test` on this child
            let result = test(name, item.childrens[i]);

            if(closeChildren){
                item.childrens[i].isOpen = false;
            }else{
                // set `item.isOpen` to true if the result is true
                // we don't do this when it is false otherwise the parent
                // would get unchecked if any of its children are unchecked
                if(result.isOpen){
                    item.isOpen = true;
                }
            }
            
            if(uncheckChildren){
                item.childrens[i].checked = false;
            }else{
                // same as above but for `item.checked`
                if(result.checked){
                    item.checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

Comment: `would it then uncheck all children recursively?` It's going to -- what should I do？

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao I've made an edit that should close/uncheck children

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Let me make a little suggestion. I suggest Posting the previous answers for others to check

Answer (score 0):

i use backtracking and should works for all occurence
and i use set and get function from Lodash

```js
let testData = [
  {
    name: "fruit",
    checked: false,
    isOpen: false,
    childrens: [
      {
        name: "apple",
        checked: false,
        isOpen: false,
        childrens: [
          {
            name: "one",
            checked: false
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "animal",
    checked: false,
    isOpen: false,
    childrens: [
      {
        name: "people",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: "123",
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  }
]

class DeepChecker {
   paths;
   value = false; 
  
   backtrack = (data, name, current) => {
        if(data.name === name){
            this.paths.push([...current]);
            return;
        }
        if(!data.childrens){
            if(data.name === name){
                this.paths.push([...current])
            }
            return;
        }


        for(let i = 0; i < data.childrens.length; i++){
            const children = data.childrens[i];
            current.push(i.toString())
            current.push("childrens");
            this.backtrack(children, name, [...current]);
            current.pop();
            current.pop();
        }
    }

    find = (data, name) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            this.backtrack(data[i], name, [i.toString(), "childrens"])
        }
    }
    
    set = (data, path) =>{
      const canBeOpen = _.get(data, [...path, "isOpen"]) !== undefined
      if(canBeOpen){
         data = _.set(data, [...path, "isOpen"], this.value)
      } 
      return _.set(data, [...path, "checked"], this.value)
    }
    
    deepCheck = (data, path) => {
        for(let i = 1; i < path.length; i+=2){
          const subpath = path.slice(0, i);
          data = this.set(data, subpath)
        }
        return data;
    }
    
    check = (data, name, value) =>{
       this.paths = []
       this.value = value;
       this.find(data, name);
       for(let i = 0; i < this.paths.length; i++){
         data = this.deepCheck(data, this.paths[i])
       }
       return data;
    }

}

const checker = new DeepChecker();


let checked = checker.check(testData, "one", true)

checked = checker.check(checked, "one", false)

checked = checker.check(checked, "people", true)

console.log(JSON.stringify(checked, null, "\t"));
```